# Lightweight DMS with built in REST API

Tags: file-management, document-management

I'm puzzling myself trying to find a tool to use with my web app for saving docs. We are rewriting our own Java web app which deals mainly with binary (MS Office) documents. In the old one, we used to store that documents in the file system using Java File APIs, but now we want to go one step further to make our different web apps be able to share the content.

The main idea is to have a centralized server which is provided with a RESTful API and will be responsible from managing the files from the applications involved. We might be also interested in:

- File versioning
- Keeping some extra metadata per file and being able to search in that metadata
- Also being able to search in file contents, but that could be covered by a framework as [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which keeps a whole index of the stored content
- Scalable tool
- Accessible through a network (kind of web server)
- We would prefer it to be open source

I've been looking though the internet and found some options like [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) but it seems to be too heavy for what we want (windows download is about 500Mb).

Anybody has an idea about that?

Answer (score 4):

So far I've found two interesting options, [LogicalDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogicalDOC) and [OpenKM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenKM). They have both comunnity (GPL licensed) versions available and a professional propietary version too. Both are:

- Runnable in a servlet container as Tomcat
- Java based
- Allow full-text searches based in Lucene
- Have a kind of API to interact with (REST-SOAP-WebDav)
- Support node versioning
- Custom metadata attributes can be added
- Got WebUI to work with

Both are enough to work as functional repositories plus search indexes for a homegrown application.

Comment: Does OpenKM work on a regular web browser without a java add-in or java extension?